When i am using custom routes file such as 'routes/admin.php' its working but when i am using 'auth' middleware its not woeking properly in laravel 11
For all of my admin route i want to using separate file 'routes/admin.php', its working fine i can visit all the routes, but when i use middleware 'auth' and i visited admin routes its redirecting to my home page. but i still cannot visit my guest routes like '/sign-in, /sign-up' cause i am allready logged in,
Note: Wen i used 'routes/web.php' all of my middleware is working fine.
How can i solve this issue??
advance thanks to all!
routes/admin.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::view('/dashboard', 'pages.backend.dashboard');


bootstrap.app.php
<?php

use App\Http\Middleware\AdminMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
        then: function () {
            Route::middleware('auth')
                ->group(base_path('routes/admin.php'));
        },
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->alias([
            'admin' => AdminMiddleware::class,
        ]);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

